# Wifi problem on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, drivers

Even when I was using Windows XP, I could only use the internet with my ethernet cable plugged in, I could never search for WiFi networks.

I thought switching to Ubuntu might fix it as new drivers will be installed etc, but it still cant connect to WiFi networks. I did `lspci` on the terminal but could not locate the `Network Controller`, only the Ethernet controller was there.

Comment: I have a feeling you don't have wifi. What laptop is it?

Comment: Its an old ass desktop, HP Compaq dx2300 microtower PC.

Answer (score 0):

The HP Compaq DX2300 Microtower PC doesn't support WiFi as far as I can tell. This is what it has:

```
Intel PRO/1000 PT Gigabit PCIe Adapter (full height)
Intel PRO/100 VE Network Connection
Agere 56K PCI Modem
```

Comment: I see , is there any way i can make it support WIFI? like buying a WIFI card or something

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessCardsSupported